# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension and getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null".  It works in the console and I made sure to close the console.  I'm trying to run this on the site below.

https://realtime.demo.sonicwall.com/main.html

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', int);      
});
function int() {
    var source = document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click;
}
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
```

popup.html

```
<body>
<button class="collapsible">Interfaces</button>
<div class="content">
<button onclick="int()" class="collapsible">Interfaces</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `html` there is no element with id `j1_64_anchor`. So your code `document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click();` will fail.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', int)
});
  
function int() {
    console.log('calling');
    var source = document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click();
}

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Interfaces</button>
<div class="content" id="j1_64_anchor">
<button onclick="int()" class="collapsible">Interfaces</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I am new to Javascript, is there anyway I can pull the elements for the current website I am using and not the HTML, maybe import it as an Iframe? That is what I was trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate you guys and I know the moderators want us to use this for help but not working on the project, so I can research this and find out.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Seems this line of code

```
function int() {
    var source = document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click;
}
```

is getting executed before the dom is ready. Try by putting it inside `DOMContentLoaded` event

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', int);   
function int() {
    var source = document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click;
}
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the DOM content is enabled:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
    function() { 
        document.getElementById('j1_64_anchor').click();
    }
);
```